# How to write router in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, router

I am a newer for vue,now i there is a simple use about vue.

```
<template>
  <div>
   .......
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      data(){

    .......
      }

    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
     .......
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
      data(){
       ....
      }
    }
</script>
```

the above is two components.
 the following is my App.vue and router:

```
    import Vue from "vue";
    import VueRouter from "vue-router";
    import home from "@/components/home.vue";
    import about from "@/components/about.vue";
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    export default new Router({
      routes : [
        {
          path:"./home",
          component:home
        },
        {
          path:"./about",
          component:about
        },
      ]
    })
<template>
    <div id = "app">
      <img src="./assets/logo.png">
      <header>
        <router-link to="/home">Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
      </header>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: ""
    }
</script>
```

this is my main.js:

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

[image]

But there is nothing about my code?
What's wrong with my code?Is there wrong about my router? How to solver it? I have confused it for a long time.Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the route path from `./home` to `/home`

```
routes : [
    {
      path:"/home",
      component: home
    },
    {
      path:"/about",
      component: about
    },
  ]
```